# opening a new url in custom popup box

Tags: jquery, popup

Can we open a new url in custom popup ? would be great if we can do that without using a plugin

```
<a href="new-page.html" class="open-popup">open</a>

<div id="popup">
   <--! page opens here -->
</div>
```

Comment: without page refresh ah?

Comment: yes, without a page refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".open-popup").click(function(event) {

     event.preventDefault();
     $("#popup").load("new-page.html");

});
```